# jQuery "Event Listener" not working with data coming from Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I am pulling text from my database and inserting into a **P TAG** that has a ***class*** that serves as a handle for my **listener**, however when I  click on the text, nothing happens the JavaScript does not react.

**Website** : http://fluentabc.com/edit.php

**Here is a Picture :**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<p class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal">
  <?php 
  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM site_edit WHERE site_sec='MainTitle'");

  while($qt = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo $MainTitle = $qt['site_txt']; // <-- I WANT TO CLICK ON THIS TEXT
  }                         
  ?>                      
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.sec_text' ,function(){

     var txt = $(this).text();
     var sec_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

     $("#curEditing").html("Your Editing : " + sec_id);
     $("#sec_edit_name").val(sec_id);

     tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(txt);

});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? try changing `$(document.body)` to just `$(document)`

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @j08691 none, no errors. Was the first place I checked.

Comment: heh "Learn English Today!" -> "Contact Us today for a free *trail*"

Comment: You said clicking on the text doesn't do anything. Are you sure? have you added any form of debugging into the event listener to see if it's firing?

Comment: I just check the source code. Actually, the `p` tag with attribute `data-reveal-id` is different than the `p` tag with text.
`<div id="MainTitle" class="">
      
      <p class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal">
    
        </p><p>Learn English Today!</p>       
       <p></p>
      
      </div>`
 the `p` tag which have `data-revel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just update your html code 100% working:

Your output should be like this:

```
<p class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal">Learn English Today!</p>
```

**Update HTML:**

```
<p class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal">
  <?php 
  $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM site_edit WHERE site_sec='MainTitle'");

  while($qt = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $MainTitle = strip_tags($qt['site_txt']); // <-- I WANT TO CLICK ON THIS TEXT
  }                         
  ?>                      
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little further? What did you do?

Comment: Again, *what did you do*?

Comment: Output of html look like this: `<p class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal">Learn English Today!</p>`

Comment: was it the strip_tags?

Comment: Use strip tags to remove all tags from output of html like above.. this was not in your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div>
  <?php 
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM site_edit WHERE     site_sec='MainTitle'");

 while($qt = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 echo '<p  class="sec_text" id="sec_1" data-reveal-id="myModal"'>.$qt['site_txt'].'</p>'; // <-- I WANT TO CLICK ON THIS TEXT
 }                         
?>                      
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.